# Extend monitor in Kubuntu

Tags: multiple-monitors

How Can I extend my desk in a two monitors? I have one connect to HDMI port and other to VGA port. I use Kubuntu.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `xrandr` command.

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 1366x768 --right-of DP-1
```

You can adjust the command according to your monitor resolution or your desired disposition.

Comment: The question uses a GUI showing current screen setup. Is there not a way to solve problem in the GUI without using CLI?